# Convert vertical scrolling Website to a functional horizontal scrolling website

Tags: javascript, html, css

The current code is a responsive vertical webpage with a vertical navigation
I want to convert It to a responsive horizontal webpage with left-right arrow control.

**Instances**

- When scrolling up or down with the mouse, the website should go left when scrolling up and right when scrolling down.
- When right or left arrow keys are pressed the website should scroll right or left depending on the key pressed.

My HTML code

```
    <body>
        <div class="section" id="home" data-label="Home">Home</div>
        <div class="section" id="about" data-label="About Me">About</div>
        <div class="section" id="contact" data-label="Say Hi">Contact</div>
        <script>
                function activateNavigation() {
                  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
                  const navContainer = document.createElement("nav");
                  const navItems = Array.from(sections).map((section) => {
                    return `
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-for-section="${section.id}">
                                        <a href="#${section.id}" class="nav-link"></a>
                                        <span class="nav-label">${section.dataset.label}</span>
                                    </div>
                                `;
                  });

                  navContainer.classList.add("nav");
                  navContainer.innerHTML = navItems.join("");

                  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
                    (entries) => {
                      document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link").forEach((navLink) => {
                        navLink.classList.remove("nav-link-selected");
                      });

                      const visibleSection = entries.filter((entry) => entry.isIntersecting)[0];

                      document
                        .querySelector(
                          `.nav-item[data-for-section="${visibleSection.target.id}"] .nav-link`
                        )
                        .classList.add("nav-link-selected");
                    },
                    { threshold: 0.5 }
                  );

                  sections.forEach((section) => observer.observe(section));

                  document.body.appendChild(navContainer);
                }

                activateNavigation();
        </script>
    </body>
```

My CSS

```
.section{
    height: 100vh;

.nav{
    --nav-gap : 15px;
    padding: var(--nav-gap);
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.nav-item{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    margin-bottom: var(--nav-gap);
}
.nav-link:hover ~ .nav-label{
    opacity: 1;
}
.nav-label{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
}
.nav-link{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: var(--nav-gap);
    margin-left: var(--nav-gap);
    width: var(--nav-gap);
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.nav-link-selected{
    background: #000000;
    transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to make a container div which will contain all the sections, and then make it display flex to handle sections as rows not columns.
Make sure to that the width and height of the container match the body's.
and then disable overflow-x on the container.
Now all we have to do is to get the current scroll Y position and transform it into a X one.
Since the browser does the job for us, we don't really need to calculate anything... just get paste the same Y position as an X one and it will work like a charm.

There is the script and explanations... All you have to do next is to challenge yourself to get the proper height of the website and use it as `min-height` for the `body`

*A quick hint* on your challenge: The height you'll need could be equal to the width of your container.

Good luck!

Example with your layout: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ea6yqLgr/2/)

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container")

window.addEventListener("scroll", horizontalScroll)
window.addEventListener("keydown", horizontalScroll)

function horizontalScroll(e, keyboadScrollingSpeed=30) {
  let y = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset

  if( e.type == "keydown" ) {
    if( (e.key == 'ArrowLeft' || e.key == 'ArrowRight') ) {
      const direction = e.key == 'ArrowLeft' ? -1 : 1
      y += keyboadScrollingSpeed * direction
      
      window.scrollTo({
        top: y
      })
    }
    else e.preventDefault()
  }
  
  container.scrollTo({
    left: y,
  })
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 300vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.section {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
      <p>This is some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <p>This is some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```